# Automate MySQL backup @localhost with mysqldump in Windows 8

Tags: windows, operating-system, scheduled-tasks, mysql

I'm trying to set up a task in Windows 8 to automate my localhost db dump.
I've created the task to run daily with the following command line:

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\mysqldump.exe
```

and parameters:

```
--user=root --password=donttellya --result-file=dumped.sql mydb
```

It works but doesn't terminate (running in the tasks list).

Also, I'd like to set a different name for the dumped file each day, maybe with the following pattern:

```
mydump-yymmdd-hhmmss.sql
```

How do you do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've found it.

The command to give to the scheduler is `cmd.exe`.
In the parameters, the command file to be executed:

```
/C commandfile.cmd
```

And in commandfile.cmd add date and time (without the slashes, depending on your local settings):

```
@echo off

set YEAR=%DATE:~6,4%
set MONTH=%DATE:~3,2%
set DAY=%DATE:~0,2%

"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\mysqldump.exe" --user=youruser --password=yourpwd --result-file=yourpath\backup-%YEAR%-%MONTH%-%DAY%-%time%.sql yourdb
```